# Why does my gnuradio Python module run when I load the flowgraph instead of when I click the start button?

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

This is gnuradio v3.8.5.0 running under Ubuntu 22.04, and I am having problems with something that used to work (previous version of O/S [Ubuntu 20.10] and gnuradio). I have a Python module that uses the serial port to connect to an Adafruit GPS device, which gets the latitude and longitude and makes it available to the gnuradio flowgraph. Previously, the Python module started running when I load the flowgraph into gnuradio-companion **and click the start button** (black triangle). Now, the Python module starts running **immediately** when I load the flowgraph, and blocks the flowgraph from further action, as it contains a loop to get time updates from the GPS. Further, the block that needs the data can't find the Python module; I notice that whenever I edit the Python module, the editor saves the module into /tmp.  I can't find any documentation that explains how this is now working... can anyone help?

I tried changing the name of the Python module and re-saving it, but get the same result.

Here is the grc:

```
options:
  parameters:
    author: ''
    category: '[GRC Hier Blocks]'
    cmake_opt: ''
    comment: ''
    copyright: ''
    description: ''
    gen_cmake: 'On'
    gen_linking: dynamic
    generate_options: qt_gui
    hier_block_src_path: '.:'
    id: grape_GPS_DRF
    max_nouts: '0'
    output_language: python
    placement: (0,0)
    qt_qss_theme: ''
    realtime_scheduling: ''
    run: 'True'
    run_command: '{python} -u {filename}'
    run_options: prompt
    sizing_mode: fixed
    thread_safe_setters: ''
    title: Grape19, 5 MHz
    window_size: (1000,1000)
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [8, 8]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled

blocks:
- name: decimation
  id: variable
  parameters:
    comment: ''
    value: '800'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [393, 21]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: samp_rate
  id: variable
  parameters:
    comment: ''
    value: '8000'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [184, 12]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: analog_sig_source_x_0
  id: analog_sig_source_x
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    amp: '1'
    comment: ''
    freq: '-1000'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    offset: '0'
    phase: '0'
    samp_rate: samp_rate
    type: complex
    waveform: analog.GR_COS_WAVE
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [106, 323]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: audio_source_0
  id: audio_source
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    device_name: ''
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    num_outputs: '1'
    ok_to_block: 'True'
    samp_rate: samp_rate
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [58, 113]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: blocks_float_to_complex_0
  id: blocks_float_to_complex
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    vlen: '1'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [322, 95]
    rotation: 0
    state: disabled
- name: blocks_multiply_xx_0
  id: blocks_multiply_xx
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    num_inputs: '2'
    type: complex
    vlen: '1'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [348, 326]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink_0
  id: gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    center_freqs: '[5.0]'
    checksum: 'False'
    comment: ''
    compression_level: '1'
    debug: 'False'
    dir: /media/guser/seagate1/wide/ch0
    file_cadence_ms: '1000'
    ignore_tags: 'False'
    input: fc32
    is_continuous: 'True'
    marching_periods: 'True'
    metadata: '{''lat'':unixtime_module.latitude,''long'':unixtime_module.longitude}'
    min_chunksize: '0'
    sample_rate_denominator: '1'
    sample_rate_numerator: int(samp_rate)
    start: unixtime_module.timestamp * samp_rate
    stop_on_skipped: 'False'
    stop_on_time_tag: 'False'
    subdir_cadence_s: '3600'
    uuid: grape19
    vlen: '1'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [638, 38]
    rotation: 0
    state: disabled
- name: gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink_0_0
  id: gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    center_freqs: '[5.0]'
    checksum: 'False'
    comment: ''
    compression_level: '1'
    debug: 'False'
    dir: /media/guser/RFdata/narrow16/ch0
    file_cadence_ms: '60000'
    ignore_tags: 'False'
    input: fc32
    is_continuous: 'True'
    marching_periods: 'True'
    metadata: '{''lat'':unixtime_module.latitude,''long'':unixtime_module.longitude}'
    min_chunksize: '0'
    sample_rate_denominator: '1'
    sample_rate_numerator: int(samp_rate/decimation)
    start: unixtime_module.timestamp * (samp_rate/(10*decimation))
    stop_on_skipped: 'False'
    stop_on_time_tag: 'False'
    subdir_cadence_s: '3600'
    uuid: grape19
    vlen: '1'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [691, 443]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: hilbert_fc_0
  id: hilbert_fc
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    beta: '6.76'
    comment: ''
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    num_taps: '512'
    win: firdes.WIN_HAMMING
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [139, 248]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: import_0
  id: import
  parameters:
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    imports: import time
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [294, 16]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: low_pass_filter_0
  id: low_pass_filter
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    beta: '6.76'
    comment: ''
    cutoff_freq: '50'
    decim: decimation
    gain: '1'
    interp: '1'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    samp_rate: samp_rate
    type: fir_filter_ccf
    width: '5'
    win: firdes.WIN_HAMMING
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [473, 297]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: qtgui_waterfall_sink_x_0
  id: qtgui_waterfall_sink_x
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    alpha1: '1.0'
    alpha10: '1.0'
    alpha2: '1.0'
    alpha3: '1.0'
    alpha4: '1.0'
    alpha5: '1.0'
    alpha6: '1.0'
    alpha7: '1.0'
    alpha8: '1.0'
    alpha9: '1.0'
    axislabels: 'True'
    bw: samp_rate
    color1: '0'
    color10: '0'
    color2: '0'
    color3: '0'
    color4: '0'
    color5: '0'
    color6: '0'
    color7: '0'
    color8: '0'
    color9: '0'
    comment: ''
    fc: '0'
    fftsize: '1024'
    freqhalf: 'True'
    grid: 'False'
    gui_hint: ''
    int_max: '10'
    int_min: '-140'
    label1: ''
    label10: ''
    label2: ''
    label3: ''
    label4: ''
    label5: ''
    label6: ''
    label7: ''
    label8: ''
    label9: ''
    legend: 'True'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    name: '""'
    nconnections: '1'
    showports: 'False'
    type: complex
    update_time: '0.10'
    wintype: firdes.WIN_BLACKMAN_hARRIS
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [644, 166]
    rotation: 0
    state: disabled
- name: qtgui_waterfall_sink_x_0_0
  id: qtgui_waterfall_sink_x
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    alpha1: '1.0'
    alpha10: '1.0'
    alpha2: '1.0'
    alpha3: '1.0'
    alpha4: '1.0'
    alpha5: '1.0'
    alpha6: '1.0'
    alpha7: '1.0'
    alpha8: '1.0'
    alpha9: '1.0'
    axislabels: 'True'
    bw: samp_rate/decimation
    color1: '0'
    color10: '0'
    color2: '0'
    color3: '0'
    color4: '0'
    color5: '0'
    color6: '0'
    color7: '0'
    color8: '0'
    color9: '0'
    comment: ''
    fc: '0'
    fftsize: '1024'
    freqhalf: 'True'
    grid: 'False'
    gui_hint: ''
    int_max: '10'
    int_min: '-140'
    label1: ''
    label10: ''
    label2: ''
    label3: ''
    label4: ''
    label5: ''
    label6: ''
    label7: ''
    label8: ''
    label9: ''
    legend: 'True'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    name: '""'
    nconnections: '1'
    showports: 'False'
    type: complex
    update_time: '0.10'
    wintype: firdes.WIN_BLACKMAN_hARRIS
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [723, 320]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: unixtime_module
  id: epy_module
  parameters:
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    source_code: "# this module will be imported in the into your flowgraph\n# Author;\
      \ W. Engelke, AB4EJ\n# This tries to read date, time, lat, long from Adafruit\
      \ GPS hat for use in\n# seting the start time of Digital RF dataset. If no response\
      \ from serial port,\n# defaults to using system time. \nimport serial\nimport\
      \ datetime\nimport time\nfrom datetime import timezone\n\nser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',baudrate=9600,\n\
      \ parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\n bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1,write_timeout=1)\n\
      ser.close()\nser.open()\n\nz=1\nwhile z==1:\n  x=ser.readline()\n  print(\"\
      Received \",len(x),\" bytes\")\n  if(len(x) == 0):\n    print(\"No serial response\
      \ from GPS card, defaulting to system time & location.\")\n    timestamp = int(time.time())\n\
      \    print(timestamp)\n    latitude = 0.0\n    longitude = 0.0\n    z = 0 #\
      \ drop out of loop and thus out of this module\n  else:\n    reading = x.split(b\"\
      ,\")\n\n    if reading[0] == b\"$GPRMC\" or reading[0] == b\"$GNRMC\" :\n  \
      \    print(\"found GPRMC *********************\")\n      print(\"time=\",reading[1].decode()+\"\
      Z\",\" lat=\",reading[3],reading[4],\" long=\",reading[5],reading[6],\" date=\"\
      ,reading[9])\n      if reading[3] == b'':  # GPS apparently does not have a\
      \ fix; set defaults\n        print(\"No GPS data; using defaults\")\n      \
      \  latitude = 0\n        longitude = 0\n        timestamp = int(time.time())\
      \ # use time from system clock, precision to 1 sec.\n        print(\"timestamp=\"\
      ,timestamp)\n        z = 0\n      else:\n        latitude = float(reading[3][0:2])\
      \ + float(reading[3][2:10])/60\n        if reading[4] == b\"S\":\n         \
      \ latitude = -latitude\n        print(\"latitude=\",latitude)\n      \n    \
      \    longitude = float(reading[5][0:3]) + float(reading[5][3:11])/60\n     \
      \   if reading[6] == b\"W\" :\n          longitude = -longitude\n        print(\"\
      longitude=\",longitude)\n\n        hour =       (float(reading[1].decode())\
      \ - (float(reading[1].decode()))%10000)/10000\n        minute =     ((float(reading[1].decode())\
      \ - (float(reading[1].decode()))%100)/100) - 100*hour\n        second =    \
      \  float(reading[1].decode()) - (hour * 10000) - (minute*100)\n        reading1\
      \ = reading[9].decode()\n        print(\"reading1=\", reading1)\n        DD\
      \ = reading1[0:2]\n        MM = reading1[2:4]\n        YY = int(reading1[4:6])\
      \ + 2000\n        print(\"hour: \", hour, \" minute: \",minute, \" second:\"\
      ,second)\n        print(\"DD \",DD,\" MM \", MM, \" YY \", YY)\n        dt =\
      \ datetime.datetime(int(YY), int(MM), int(DD), int(hour), int(minute), int(second))\n\
      \        timestamp = int(dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())\n    \
      \    print(timestamp)\n        z=0\n    \n"
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [505, 22]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled

connections:
- [analog_sig_source_x_0, '0', blocks_multiply_xx_0, '1']
- [audio_source_0, '0', blocks_float_to_complex_0, '0']
- [audio_source_0, '0', blocks_float_to_complex_0, '1']
- [audio_source_0, '0', hilbert_fc_0, '0']
- [blocks_float_to_complex_0, '0', gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink_0, '0']
- [blocks_float_to_complex_0, '0', qtgui_waterfall_sink_x_0, '0']
- [blocks_multiply_xx_0, '0', low_pass_filter_0, '0']
- [hilbert_fc_0, '0', blocks_multiply_xx_0, '0']
- [low_pass_filter_0, '0', gr_digital_rf_digital_rf_channel_sink_0_0, '0']
- [low_pass_filter_0, '0', qtgui_waterfall_sink_x_0_0, '0']

metadata:
  file_format: 1
```

Here is the code in the Python unixtime_module:

```
import serial
import datetime
import time
from datetime import timezone

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',baudrate=9600,
 parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
 bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1,write_timeout=1)
ser.close()
ser.open()

z=1
while z==1:
  x=ser.readline()
  print("Received ",len(x)," bytes")
  if(len(x) == 0):
    print("No serial response from GPS card, defaulting to system time & location.")
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    print(timestamp)
    latitude = 0.0
    longitude = 0.0
    z = 0 # drop out of loop and thus out of this module
  else:
    reading = x.split(b",")

    if reading[0] == b"$GPRMC" or reading[0] == b"$GNRMC" :
      print("found GPRMC *********************")
      print("time=",reading[1].decode()+"Z"," lat=",reading[3],reading[4]," long=",reading[5],reading[6]," date=",reading[9])
      if reading[3] == b'':  # GPS apparently does not have a fix; set defaults
        print("No GPS data; using defaults")
        latitude = 0
        longitude = 0
        timestamp = int(time.time()) # use time from system clock, precision to 1 sec.
        print("timestamp=",timestamp)
        z = 0
      else:
        latitude = float(reading[3][0:2]) + float(reading[3][2:10])/60
        if reading[4] == b"S":
          latitude = -latitude
        print("latitude=",latitude)
      
        longitude = float(reading[5][0:3]) + float(reading[5][3:11])/60
        if reading[6] == b"W" :
          longitude = -longitude
        print("longitude=",longitude)

        hour =       (float(reading[1].decode()) - (float(reading[1].decode()))%10000)/10000
        minute =     ((float(reading[1].decode()) - (float(reading[1].decode()))%100)/100) - 100*hour
        second =      float(reading[1].decode()) - (hour * 10000) - (minute*100)
        reading1 = reading[9].decode()
        print("reading1=", reading1)
        DD = reading1[0:2]
        MM = reading1[2:4]
        YY = int(reading1[4:6]) + 2000
        print("hour: ", hour, " minute: ",minute, " second:",second)
        print("DD ",DD," MM ", MM, " YY ", YY)
        dt = datetime.datetime(int(YY), int(MM), int(DD), int(hour), int(minute), int(second))
        timestamp = int(dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
        print(timestamp)
        z=0
```

I posted the code as requested, but I don't think this has anything to do with the code, since all the code used to work fine. I have the impression that something related to [Python Modules](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Python_Module)  changed in the most recent version of gnuradio.  Is it perhaps now necessary to put the python module into a specific directory?

Comment: This will be impossible to answer without seeing your code!

Comment: OK, I can add code, but the more fundamental question is this:  is it normal behavior that gnuradio runs all the Python Modules when the grc is opened/loaded (prior to when the user clicks the run button (black triangle)) ?

Comment: I don't know what "running a module" would mean. I really can't answer what you ask me to answer without seeing your code – and I've been writing Python for around 14 years and have spend ~3years as GNU Radio's lead architect.

Comment: Here is the type of module I am talking about: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Python_Module .  I created a Python Module block in my grc named unixtime_module (will try to post the code). I reference the results (variable content) of running the module in several blocks, but it does not find the variable contents (this used to work). I will also try to post the grc.

Comment: I need **your** code. Not gonna be able to speculate about what you mean with "running a module", nor what your code's problem is – I'm sorry, but I'll have to vote to close this as in need of necessary information. Your code is not optional when discussing your code, and I asked you three times.

Comment: The code is there now.

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm confused: you're setting up the serial connection the moment the module is loaded, which inherently must happen when the flow graph is built – so, that would seem to be the behaviour the code is designed to exhibit! So, maybe, was the idea to put this all in a code snippet? But then you don't get a python module to import; I guess that means you'll want to move all code there is in your `unixtime_module` inside a function in that gets called from the rest of your code (or, for example, a Python snippet?) at the right time?

Comment: The way this was working before was that unixtime_module would start running when you click the start button in gnuradio (the black triangle), and its result variables would be accessible in the grc blocks (e.g., unixtime_module.timestamp). How should I set this up so that unixtime_module runs when the user starts the flowgraph?

Comment: as said, move all that code from the module into a function in that module, and then add a "Python Snippet" that calls that function – at the right point in time.